# Android, finding specific object on photo

Tags: android, image-processing

Im new with android and I'm looking for some tolls that i could separate some specific objects like for example cars from background. Should I use openCV libary ? It might be done by loading image from storage or directly from camera preview. Whats the best way to achive that ?

Comment: You're going to have to use a 3rd party library (unless you want to write your own.  Good luck if so).  Which to use is off topic here.

Comment: Use https://code.google.com/p/openanpr/, i ve used it recently for a customer and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define 3 things.

1. List item the image you provided should be with good representation of a target region.
2. Information regarding you target relative location
3. different viewing angles and various distances.

try FAST algorithm

you can find more here:

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_fast/py_fast.html